# SCCM deploy from VMware XP image

Tags: sccm

We recently set up the latest version of SCCM and I managed to capture a .wim image from a virtual machine (build and capture task sequence). I want to use this .wim file to deploy winXP to different hardware, and therefor need to add device drivers to the task sequence.

I created a driver package per laptop type, and deployed for the first time. However, I am getting a BSOD (0x00007B) which leads me to believe theres a problem with the storage drivers. After adjusting the task sequence to try and point to the mass storage drivers (which are applied at F6, I suppose) I do not get a list of compatible drivers (the list is empty). I looked around, and found some issues regarding hdc class drivers that are not recognized as mass storage drivers. The workaround suggested changing the INF file to make the driver a SCSIAdapter class driver, and importing these again, but to no avail. The list remains empty.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

We've had some difficutly with Windows XP OSD in SCCM, primarily because XP is HAL dependent.  I know that you should be able to specify the drivers as part of the OSD task sequence, but we could never get this to work right.

In the end, we created different WIMs for the machines that needed specialized drivers (using the correct physical workstation model for the reference image) and added WMI conditions within the OSD task sequence to pick the appropriate WIM.  This has worked well for us.  Unfortunately, you will need to have reference models available in your development lab to do it this way.

Comment: I agree, we wound up not going this route b/c of how diverse the workstations in our environment are, but we ran into the same issue b/c of XP being HAL based. Also, since we are in the process of migrating everyone to Win 7, we have a RIS server that XP (among other things) is deployed from.